# Custom route with more than one parameter in url (customer, extra info)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, controller

I have a multi tenant system and I need to allow administrators to edit the information of other customers.

I believe the correct way to do this is to append the customer ID to each request, and update my routes accordingly.

How do I make ASP.NET accept and use something like this in the controller (order doesn't mean much to me):

mysite.com/files/delete/{file}/{customerID}

and how would I pass and consume that in my controller? The ASP.NET tutorials skip this... (or I don't know where to search)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a route:

```
            //mysite.com/files/delete/{file}/{customerID}
            routes.MapRoute(
                "Files", // Route name
                "files/delete/{file}/{customerID}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "File", action = "Delete" } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

Create a Controller:

```
    public class FileController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Delete(string file, string customerID)
        {
            //do something
            return View();
        }

    }
```

I presume that {file} is a filename that should be deleted.